# TailwindCss: Local font not showing (in Vue 3)

Tags: css, vue.js, font-face, tailwind-css

I try to embed local fonts in CSS, but the font is not shown. Browsers says, it is the locale font, Editor completion works too (text-...) but the font looks different.

I ran: `npx tailwindcss build -i src/assets/styles/index.css --output src/assets/styles/tailwind.css` for build.

### Where my files are

```
src/assets/fonts/IBM_Plex_Sans/IBMPlexSans-Italic.ttf
src/assets/fonts/Inter/Inter-Bold.ttf
```

### How I imported the files

```
/*index.css*/
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;

@layer base {
  @font-face {
    font-family: 'IBM Plex Sans', sans-serif;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
    src: local('IBM Plex Sans'), local('IBMPlexSans'), url('../fonts/IBM_Plex_Sans/IBMPlexSans-Italic.ttf') format('ttf');
  }
  
  @font-face {
    font-family: 'Inter', sans-serif;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
    src: local('Inter'), local('Inter'), url('../fonts/Inter/Inter-Bold.ttf') format('ttf');
  }
}
```

No difference with or without quotes after url(

### How I hooked them up in the config

```
tailwind.config.js
module.exports = {
...
  theme: {
    extend: {
      fontFamily: {
        // https://tailwindcss.com/docs/font-family#customizing
        ibmplexsans: ["'IBM Plex Sans'"],
        inter: ["'Inter'"],
      },
    },
  },
...
};
```

### How I use them, in a Vue component

```
<span class=" font-ibmplexsans italic text-blue-600">publish</span>
```

Same with and without 'italic'
It works fine with:

```
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=IBM+Plex+Sans:ital,wght@0,600;1,400;1,600&family=Inter:wght@600&display=swap");
```

How can I achiev that with local files.

Answer (score 0):

**Arrange the files this way**

```
public/fonts/IBM_Plex_Sans/IBMPlexSans-Italic.ttf
public/fonts/Inter/Inter-Bold.ttf
```

**Also, place index.css along this path**

```
public/fonts/index.css
```

**With content like this**

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'IBM Plex Sans', sans-serif;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: local('IBM Plex Sans'), local('IBMPlexSans'), url('./IBM_Plex_Sans/IBMPlexSans-Italic.ttf') format('ttf');
}
```

**В public/index.html**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/fonts/index.css">
```